# Overlaying animation camerapreview

Tags: android, animation, android-camera, android-animation, preview

I use CameraPreview as a background of an Acitivity which should also contain some elements like Button and ImageView. Button click make animation starts inside of the ImageView. I managed to add and display Button, but if I add ImageView the application crashes. Please help.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/playselector" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/anim" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

 private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    AnimationDrawable mAnim;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        /* ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.anim.blanim);
        mAnim = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground(); */ this part make app crash


       Button button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                mAnim.start();
        }

        }); 
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        return c; 
    }
}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace. i see you have commented `mAnim = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `image.setImageResource(R.anim.blanim);` use `image.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.blanim);` for more info have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

Comment: add stack trace, that will help to find exact cause

Comment: Excuse me, but how can I do that? Is it possible to do if I don't use Emulator?